# Inbuilt functions to obfuscate password

Tags: java, hash, passwords, obfuscation

Are there any two-way hashing algorithms built into Java that will allow me to obfuscate a password?

Two-way as I need the plain text back.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what *hashing* is.

Comment: If you need the plaintext back, you're doing passwords wrong.

Comment: See the answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639725/a-two-way-string-hash-function

Comment: Hashing is a one-way action and should normally be used to store passwords. If you really really need the original password, e.g. to send it to another service, then the best you can do is to _encrypt_ the passwords. There are many good encrypting algorithms like twofish or aes, the problem is always where to store the key.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a hashhing algorithm is that it is one-way.

However, you can use something like base64 encoding to obfuscate a String.

Be aware that passwords should be hashed one-way. It is not very trustworthy when you only "obfuscate" your users' passwords and you can re-create them in plain text at any time...

Answer (score 0):

Hashing is one-way - that's kind of the point. (hint: the domain of a hash function is much larger than the range... therefore for any point in the range, there are many points in the domain, therefore it can't be inverted)

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in function to encrypt passwords in Java. However you can hash them, however hashing is one way, which will not allow you to retrieve the original text.

You can however use a Stream Cipher to encrypt and decrypt text.

You can try the [Rabbit Stream Cipher](https://github.com/Chase-san/Maru/tree/master/src/org/csdgn/maru/crypto).